# How is it possible to transfer Internet Explorer (11) security settings without registry?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, security-policy

I have set up a PC with Internet Explorer 11 and its security settings to let it work with the customer's Web Application.

I now want to transfer these IE settings - mainly security setting - so that customer can easily import to his machine. I don't want to change regional and language settings.

Is this possible anyhow without using registry export/import? It should be easy to use, so it can also be used by untrained users. ;)